# argparse optional positional argument and subparsers arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python script that takes in an optional positional argument and has a few subcommands. Some of these subcommands require the positional argument, some don't. The problem I have appears when I try to use a subcommand that does not require the positional argument. Consider the following test file:

```
import argparse

argp = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argp.add_argument('inputfile', type=str, nargs='?',
                  help='input file to process')
argp.add_argument('--main_opt1', type=str,
                  help='global option')

subp = argp.add_subparsers(title='subcommands',
                           dest='parser_name',
                           help='additional help',
                           metavar="<command>")

tmpp = subp.add_parser('command1', help='command1 help')
tmpp.add_argument('pos_arg1', type=str,
                  help='positional argument')

print repr(argp.parse_args())
```

When I try to use the subcommand `command1` with the first argument everything goes well.

```
macbook-pro:~ jmlopez$ python pytest.py filename command1 otherarg
Namespace(inputfile='filename', main_opt1=None, parser_name='command1', pos_arg1='otherarg')
```

But now let us assume that `command1` doesn't need the first positional argument.

```
macbook-pro:~ jmlopez$ python pytest.py command1 otherarg
usage: pytest.py [-h] [--main_opt1 MAIN_OPT1] [inputfile] <command> ...
pytest.py: error: argument <command>: invalid choice: 'otherarg' (choose from 'command1')
```

I was somehow expecting `inputfile` to be set to `None`. Is there any way that `argparse` can predict that `command1` is actually a subcommand and thus `inputfile` should be set to None?

Answer (score 5):

To `argp` the subparser argument looks just like another positional, one that takes choices (the names of the subparsers).  Also `argp` knows nothing about `pos_arg1`.  That's in `tmpp`'s list of arguments.

When `argp` sees `filename command1 otherarg`, `filename` and `command1` satisfy its 2 positionals.  `otherarg` is then passed on the `tmpp`.

With `command1 otherarg`, again 2 strings, 2 `argp` positionals.  `command` is assigned to `inputfile`.  There's no logic to backtrack and say `command1` fits `subcommands` better, or that `tmpp' needs one of those strings.

You could change the 1st positional to an optional, `--inputfile`.

Or you could `inputfile` another positional of `tmpp`.  If a number of the subparsers need it it, consider using `parents`.

`argparse` isn't a smart as you, and can't 'think ahead' or 'backtrack'.  If it appears to do something smart it's because it uses `re` pattern matching to handle `nargs` values (e.g. ?, *, +).

EDIT

One way to 'trick' argparse into recognizing the first positional as the subparser is to insert an optional after it.  With `command1 -b xxx otherarg`, `-b xxx` breaks up the list of positional strings, so  only `command1` is matched against `inputfile` and `subcommands`.

```
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('file',nargs='?',default='foo')
sp = p.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
spp = sp.add_parser('cmd1')
spp.add_argument('subfile')
spp.add_argument('-b')

p.parse_args('cmd1 -b x three'.split())
# Namespace(b='x', cmd='cmd1', file='foo', subfile='three')
```

The issue here is how `argparse` handles postionals with variable `nargs`.  The fact that the 2nd positional is a subparser is not important.   While `argparse` allows variable length positionals in any order, how it handles them can be confusing.  It's easier to predict what `argparse` will do if there is only one such positional, and it occurs at the end.

Comment: It seems that way. I guess the only way to achieve what I want is to preparse `sys.argv` and insert a default inputfile or default command if needed and then let `argparse` do its job.

Comment: Is it important to have `inputfile` occur before the `subcommands`?  Usually (as in programs like `git`) the subparser is the first positional argument.  If `inputfile` is handled in a special way by `command1`, I would expect to name it near the end of the command line.

Comment: I've added a partial solution - adding an `optional` (flagged) argument to the subparse to break up the list of `positional` strings.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell the parser that the first argument is different type.
try adding flags option and default `None` value like this:

```
argp.add_argument('-i','--inputfile', type=str, nargs='?',
              help='input file to process',default=None)
```

now, you need to add `-i` before the inputfile argument, but it will work fine.

```
macbook-pro:~ jmlopez$ python pytest.py -i filename command1 otherarg
Namespace(inputfile='filename', main_opt1=None, parser_name='command1', pos_arg1='otherarg')
```

and

```
macbook-pro:~ jmlopez$ python pytest.py command1 otherarg
Namespace(inputfile=None, main_opt1=None, parser_name='command1', pos_arg1='otherarg')
```

Comment: Having it as I had before I could do `macbook-pro:~ jmlopez$ python pytest.py _ command1 otherarg` to let python know that the input argument is empty. I rather have an option say `--cmd` to specify that the first keyword is a command instead of it being the input.